# Trying to deploy a python script to staging bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, dialogflow-es

For use with dialogflow I've been deploying index.js javascript files to google cloud sdk staging bucket using:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy projName --staging-bucket projName.appspot.com 
--trigger-http
```

Today I tried to switch from javascript to python because I know it a little better.

I hoped it would be as simple as replacing index.js with index.py but the deployment still searches for index.js.

The error message I get is message=Function load error: File index.js or junction.js that is expected to define function does not exist in the root directory.

I got the impression it would be a simple switch because I'm using the webhook script provided by dialogflow themselves on here:
https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-webhook-weather-python

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to deploy a cloud function, but as far as I know, you can't write Google cloud functions in Python. Javascript is the only supported language at this time.

See, for example, https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/

If you want to deploy Python code, you are going to need some other method; maybe AppEngine, which is what it looks like the code you linked to was using.

Comment: Thank you, I ended up deploying on Heroku instead, it works great!